# Singular value decomposition under linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with singular values $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n$ and corresponding right singular vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ and let $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ whose singular values are all in the interval $[1-\epsilon, 1+\epsilon]$ for some $\epsilon > 0$.

Denote by $\sigma'_1,\ldots,\sigma'_n$ the singular values of $BA$ with right singular vectors $v'_1, \ldots, v'_n$.

Prove that $|v_i^{'T}A^TAv'_j| \leq O(\epsilon)\sigma_i\sigma_j$.

My attempt:

I was able to prove that for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ , $(1-\epsilon)\|Ax\| \leq \|BAx\| \leq (1+\epsilon)\|Ax\|$, and then by Cauchy-Schwartz,

$$|v_i^{'T}A^TAv'_j| \leq \|Av'_i\|\|Av'_j\| \leq (1 - \epsilon)^{-1}\|BAv'_i\|\|BAv'_j\| = (1 - \epsilon)^{-1}\sigma'_i\sigma'_j$$

But now I'm stuck. I would appreciate any help.